# Why does spring-boot-starter-logging require a dependency on log4-to-slf4j

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j

I have a Spring Boot 2.6.3 project that uses `spring-boot-starter`. When I run the `dependecy:tree` goal in maven, I see that `spring-boot-starter-logging` depends on both `logback` and (indirectly) `log4j`. Why does `spring-boot-starter-logging` require a dependency on `log4-to-slf4j`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot has bindings for all major logging frameworks. With a single configuration you can concentrate logs sent through SLF4J, Log4j 2.x API or `java.util.logging`.

Therefore the [`spring-boot-starter-logging`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging) provides:

- a logging backend ([`logback-classic`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic)), which uses SLF4J as native API,
- a bridge from the Log4j 2.x API to SLF4J ([`log4j-to-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j)). Remark that this is not the standard Log4j 2.x Core implementation.
- a bridge/handler from `java.util.logging` to SLF4J ([`jul-to-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.33)).

Remark that [`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2) does the same thing and redirects the frameworks above to Log4j 2.x Core.

The big absent in this picture is Jakarta Commons Logging, which is only able to bind to `java.util.logging` (hence not directly to neither Logback nor Log4j 2.x Core). However `spring-core` depends on [`spring-jcl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jcl), which binds JCL directly to SLF4J or the Log4j 2.x API and can entirely replace the original JCL.

A fifth API (Log4j 1.x) was supported in Spring Boot 1.x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with “ Remark that this is not the standard Log4j 2.x Core implementation.”?

Comment: `log4j-core` and `log4j-to-slf4j` are two separate implementations of the Log4j 2.x API. The one unfortunately famous is `log4j-core`, while `log4j-to-slf4j` was not vulnerable.

Comment: Found this answer while looking for an explanation why they use log4j-to-slf4j in combination with log4j-api instead of log4j-over-slf4j. Do you happen to know that?

Comment: `log4j-to-slf4j` is a bridge from Log4j 2 API (notice the 2) to SLF4J. `log4j-over-slf4j` is a Log4j 1.x **replacement** that forwards everything to SLF4J.

Comment: So version 1 vs version 2 is the reason. Thank you