# Problem with log4j2 to write all logs to a specific file in Spring Boot 3.1.0 with Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, log4j2

I am trying to set log4j2 to write all logs to a specific file. I've tried various things I found on the internet but still the logs only show up in the console.

I am using **IntelliJ IDEA CE**.
**Spring Boot** version is 3.1.0.
**Java** version is 17.
**Maven** version is 4.0.0.

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring WebSocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The log4j2.xml located in src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="app.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**I tried the following things:**

- I added exclusions for logback-classic in spring-boot-starter-security and spring-boot-starter-web
- I removed unused Logging Configurations
- I verified Log4j2 Configuration
- Log4j2 Internal Status Logger
- There is no application's logs and console output for any error messages or warnings related to logging
- I tried a minimal metup
- I added LogManager.getContext(false); in public static void main(String[] args)

Can someone help me solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong in configuration file of log4j2, share you property file.

Comment: Also does even you file exist ? if its not make 'append' key to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding Logback is **not** enough. The [`spring-boot-starter-logging`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging) takes care of connecting all major logging APIs to Logback (cf. [What is Spring Boot Starter Log4J2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75719238/11748454) and [Why does spring-boot-starter-logging require a dependency on log4-to-slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71176985/11748454) for details). In particular it contains [`log4j-to-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j), which is an implementation of the Log4j 2 API that forwards everything to SLF4J.

You need to remove `spring-boot-starter-logging` from your dependencies and replace it with [`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2). The usual trick is to:

- explicitly add [`spring-boot-starter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter) to your dependencies: it is the only starter that depends on `spring-boot-starter-logging`, all other starters depends on `spring-boot-starter`,
- exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` from it:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  ```
- add `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` and the logging API of your choice:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- remove all other explicit `log4j-*` dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I had similar problem and it was quite frustrating to figure out the root cause for this.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Log file (in your case app.log) exit ?

In case not, on the configuration file in `Appender` tag make the property `append` to false, see more in [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).

```
<Appenders>
    <File name="FILE" fileName="app.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
```

> Are you getting the proper logger from [LoggerFactory](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html)?

Make sure you getting logger by the **name** you crated the configuration.

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FILE");
```